# TLC5940 Software library for stm32cube IDE

Tags: c++, stm32, stm32cubeide

I’m a student from KU-Leuven university in Belgium and for a project I use 3 TLC5940's to drive a 16x16 RGB Led matrix. I want to use the STM32CUBE IDE to write the software.
Now because my software skills are not the best I searched for an existing library. I found a library that works on the Mbed compiler (https://os.mbed.com/users/Spencer/code/TLC5940/) to use it in STM32CUBE IDE there are a lot of things that needs to be translated to work. Is there a easy way to translate or is there any chance this library exist for the stm32cube IDE?
Kind regards
Roeland Osaer

Comment: I assume you mean "a library that works on mbed OS" ? You probably have to replace the calls to mbed APIs (timers, SPI etc...) by calls to STMicro HAL APIs.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. But like I said, my software skill are not that good and I'm having troubles finding out the correct way to translate these.